# Using single stored procedure for different data imports to different tables

Tags: sql, .net, sql-server, ssis

I am in a designing stage of an application, I have a huge functionality of importing data into a SQL Server database. As there are numerous tables in database, I want to avoid conventional based approach of creating models and writing stored procedures for each Import. Is there a way by which I can use create single stored procedure for different tables and insert data into them?

Note: columns will vary from table to table.

Thanks in advance

Comment: Sounds like a really bad idea, since if everything is dynamic (table and their columns), you'll have to work with a lot of dynamic SQL and this gets messy very quickly. I would definitely vote for more conventional approaches, e.g. SSIS packages focused on just **one** import at a time (honoring the **Single Responsibility Principle** of design, too)

Comment: marc_s: I would end up creating 400+ models and sp's for just importing...
can't we use table type and use it dynamically?

Comment: @MohammedAZHARUDDIN, if columns vary from table to table, wouldn't you need varying table types too?

Comment: @dan guzman,if that's the case. cannot i use Json type in sql, take a string param as input and performing some dynamic operation  while insertion?

Comment: And if you're trying to create a "generic" procedure that can deal with 400+ different sets of data and tables - this is going to very quickly become a ***maintenance monster and nightmare*** - seriously - don't do it. Yes, creating 400+ procedures is a lot of coding - maybe you can generate some of that code - but at least when you need to fix something, you'll know which procedure to go to, and it will be small, and simple to understand with the hope of being able to fix if anything is wrong. Such a generic "do-it-all" monster won't be maintainable......

Answer (score 0):

Well, I would stick to comments discouraging it, but on other hand, if this procedure will be super simple and maintenance will be transferred to JSON creator, you can do it like this:

```
declare @tablename as nvarchar(max)
declare @json as nvarchar(max)

declare @query as nvarchar(max)

set @tablename = (SELECT TableName FROM YourAllowedTableNamesList WHERE Tablename = @tablename)

Set @query = 
  'Insert into ' + @tablename + 
  'SELECT * FROM OPENJSON(' + @json + ')'

Exec (@query)
```

Answer (score 0):

Yes I have done something like this at my current shop.  Your question is too broad so I will give you only a broad overview of what we have done.

We wrote a console app that gets a SQL Command from a meta table and executes it on the source into an in-memory DataTable.   It then bulk-inserts that data into a staging table on the destination database.

Then we run a generic merge proc that looks at the system tables to get the Primary Keys and datatypes of the final destination table and constructs INSERT and UPDATE statements using dynamic sql.

Despite the well-meaning warnings of others, it's working well for us, though it does have some limitations, such as an inability to handle BLOB datatypes in a generic way.   There may be other limitations that we just haven't encountered yet as well.